# How do I improve my house?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I received a book that told me I need to talk to someone to improve my house in Whiterun.

Who is this person, and where can I find them?

Comment: I was so avid for an answer, misreading the question as "how do I improve my **mouse**"?

Comment: Are you looking for http://diy.stackexchange.com ? ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The same person you bought the house from also sells the furnishing for it. For the house in Whiterun (Breezehome) this person is Proventus Avenicci, who you usually find near the Jarl.

Comment: If he's not near the Jarl, he'll be on the Grand Porch. Took me forever to find him .:)

Comment: Note: I've found that the option to buy upgrades isn't available when he is in his quarters.

Comment: i've found that the option to buy upgrades wasn't available at all until he was in front of the throne.

Comment: Yep as Canageek says, if you can't find a way to buy upgrades and Avenicci is in his sleeping quarters etc, then make sure to sleep a few hours till everyone is in the main dragonreach areas. he will then allow buying furniture

Answer (score 0):

You can buy and furnish the Breezehome away from the throne and bedroom.

Go up the stairs on the right of the throne and wait by the table with the maps. At about 6 AM Proventus comes out and will sell you the house and furnishings while he looks at the maps.

Less chance of interruptions by others and you get it all done in one meeting.

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is find the man that you bought your house from and there should be a option to decorate your home.

Comment: This adds nothing not already said.

Answer (score -2):

You talk to Proventus, the Jarl's Steward (unless you've completed the civil war side quest).

Comment: This doesn't add anything over the existing answer.

Comment: This answer adds nothing not already covered by existing answers. Duplicate answers help nobody and may be deleted.