# Why can't I improve my house in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can't upgrade the inside of my house](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38609/i-cant-upgrade-the-inside-of-my-house)

I purchased a house in Whiterun and didn't improve/decorate it when I purchased it.

Now, I don't seem to have the option of improving it. As mentioned in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/36492/200), I went over to Proventus Avenicci, but the option [isn't there](http://steamcommunity.com/id/sathyabhat/screenshot/612717879304151407).

With 1,520 gold I do believe I have enough, so why isn't the option there?

Comment: Leave and come back or wait 24 hours and that should do the trick.

Comment: This does look like a dupe, but I'm 90% sure [it's because of where he is](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/38786/3389). Wait around or do other stuff until he goes back into the throne room.

Comment: Why didn't you leave this as a comment on Fabian's answer?